# Dojo "Select" widget and a hierarchical store

Tags: dijit.form, dojo

I am trying to mimic the behaviour of the  tag from HTML in a *dijit.form.Select* widget. From what I've read through the tickets posted on the dojo issue tracker this can be accomplished using hierarchical stores. I created such a store, but the dropdown only displays only the "group names" and not the children.

Does anybody know if a *dijit.form.Select* widget even works with a hierarchical store?

Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: Youre referring to the HTML tag 'optgroup'? Afaik the Select widget operates entirely with name/value pairs, see http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/form/__SelectOption

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it doesn't work so I changed my implementation entirely (i.e. the user chooses what to display in the *Select* control, as opposed to display the data in the *Select* using *optgroup*)